# PostGIS ogr_fdw foreign data wrapper ERROR: column "date" of foreign table 'mytable' converts OGR "String" to "date"

Tags: ubuntu, ogr-fdw, postgresql-14

Using the [ogr_fdw](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-ogr-fdw) extension on PG 14 PostGIS 3.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I am trying to register a foreign table in my local PostgreSQL database based on an OGC API Feature endpoint serving GeoJSON features as follow:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION ogr_fdw;

CREATE SERVER "my_server"
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER ogr_fdw
    OPTIONS (
        datasource 'OAPIF:https://server.org/pygeoapi/collections/my_collection',
        format 'OAPIF' );

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE my_collection (
    id bigint,
    geometry Geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
    name VARCHAR(40),
    title TEXT,
    measure_date DATE,
    length NUMERIC
    )
    SERVER "my_server"
    OPTIONS (layer 'my_collection');
```

But then, this query raises an error:

```
SELECT id, geometry, name, title, measure_date, length
    FROM public.my_collection;


ERROR:  column "measure_date" of foreign table "my_collection" converts OGR "String" to "date"
SQL state: HV004
```

Is this a known bug or did I miss something somewhere?

Note: it works very well if I remove the `measure_date` field from all these queries.

##### Versioning information:

```
PostgreSQL 14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
  compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, 64-bit
```

```
POSTGIS="3.2.0 c3e3cc0" [EXTENSION]
  PGSQL="140"
  GEOS="3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0""
  PROJ="8.2.1"
  LIBXML="2.9.12"
  LIBJSON="0.15"
  LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
  WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
```

On the `ogr_fdw` extension table:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS ogr_fdw
    SCHEMA public
    VERSION "1.1";
```

Comment: I guess that your pygeoapi serves data as GeoJSON. GeoJSON does not have a native data type for dates, but GDAL tries to find strings which look like dates/datetimes. Sometimes it does not recognize them right. Create column "measure_date" as a string because that's what you get from pygeoapi. You can cast the strings which are presenting dates into real dates in the database.  Add a sample of the data from the pygeoapi service and the schema from `ogrinfo OAPIF:https://server.org/pygeoapi/collections/my_collection -so` and we would not need to guess as much.

Comment: Would you mind giving some information about how it goes?